# how to copy the contents of a last modified file from a folder to the other folder using java?

Tags: java

*i am trying  to copy the contents of a last modified file from a folder to the other folder using java*

*i am able to move the file but i am unable to move the contents of the file*

```
private File getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath) throws IOException{
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
    return null;
}

File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
   if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
       lastModifiedFile = files[i];
   }
}
String newFilePath = "C:\\newPath\\"+lastModifiedFile.getName();
Path temp = Files.move 
        (Paths.get(dirPath), 
        Paths.get(newFilePath )); 

        if(temp != null) 
        { 
            System.out.println("File renamed and moved successfully"); 
        } 
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("Failed to move the file"); 
        } 
 return new File(newFilePath );
}
```

Result : only file is moving but not contents

Comment: So in the end you have a void file and orphan content ?!?

Comment: empty file without contents

Comment: i need to move the contents of last modified file

Comment: Is the source file also on drive C: ? If not, can you post the source file path? Is the source file a link or an actual file? Is the source file a normal file, for example a text file?

Comment: yeah it is in C drive

Answer (score 0):

Rather use the [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library and more specifically [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). It's a very nice library that works really well with what your trying to do.

```
File sourceFile = new File(...);
File destinationFile = new File(...);
FileUtils.moveFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

Used it quite successfully on a small project I did a while back ([FilingAssistant](https://github.com/ambro-r/FilingAssistant))